# How do I set the DataSource as Mi Band 2(or anything other than my phone) for finding the sensors for counting steps using Google Fit?

Tags: android, google-fit

I a noob in android.

I am able to get the step data from my phone, but i want the data of my fitness band ie mi Band 2. Till now I have been able to connect the Band using the conventional method of connecting the BLE devices. After connection I am not able to get the data from the Band.

Is it even possible to get the Band data using Google Fit API or shall I do it using the Mi-Band-SDK available on GitHub : https://github.com/pangliang/miband-sdk-android ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Google Fit API, then you need to check this documentation on how to [List available data sources](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors#list_available_data_sources).

It is explained here that to get information about the device for a data source, use the [`DataSource.getDevice`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataSource) method. The device information is useful to distinguish from similar sensors on different devices, show the device information from a sensor to the user, or process data differently depending on the device.

For the Github that you link, I'm not sure if this is still working. As you can see here they already stopped the maintenance in this Github, but you can still give a try here and check if it's still working.

I found here another [Github](https://github.com/betomaluje/Mi-Band) that might help you.

Comment: I've been through this documentation on how to list all the available data sources and i did use the this DataSource.getDevice() method to display all the available Data sources of the type TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA. But that list didn't have my device which I had connected to the app using the conventional method of connecting the BLE devices. Actually I think the connectivity must be done using the BLE_API in Fitness API.

Comment: I am currently connecting the device in an Activity and then passing the device in the Intent to another Activity. And then getting the device by using the getParcelableExtra() method. Now I somehow know that i need to use the EXTRA_DATA_SOURCE type in the setDataSourceType() attribute of DataSourceRequest() method, but here the problem is the EXTRA_DATA_SOURCE is a string type variable whereas the setDataSourceType() method needs an Integer argument. If you are familiar with this Fitness API, then I need help. 
Also I've been through the Github Link, but it is for Miband 1 not for Miband 2